# Why do I need to include multiple .js files in default.htm when working with typescript in visual studio?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, typescript

I'm just starting out with typescript.  I wanted to try working with [this mankala example](http://typescript.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#samples/mankala/play.htm) from within Visual Studio. Eventually I got it working but I had to include all of the .js files that were generated from .ts files in my default.htm file.  The .htm file in the example only included one file - the one that contained the entry point.  I'm guessing that there's something set wrong in my configuration that I'm compensating for by the multiple .js includes.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

More details follow...

Here's what the original .htm file looked like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Mankala</title>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="game.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="play.css"/>  
</head>
<body id="bod" onload="Mankala.testBrowser()">
   <div class="hscore">Human: <span id="humscore">0</span></div>
   <div class="cscore">Computer: <span id="compscore">0</span></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is what my modified .htm file looked like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Mankala</title>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="base.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Driver.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Features.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Game.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="geometry.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Position.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="play.css"/>  
</head>
<body id="bod" onload="Mankala.testBrowser()">
   <div class="hscore">Human: <span id="humscore">0</span></div>
   <div class="cscore">Computer: <span id="compscore">0</span></div>
</body>
</html>
```

To create the project I created a default ( not quite empty ) typescript project, deleted the automatically created app.ts file from that project and then added 6 new .ts files with the same names as the .ts files in the example.  Then I copied the .ts files from the example over the new .ts files that were created by VS.  I replaced the automatically generated app.css file with the play.css file from the example and replaced the contents of the automatically generated default.htm file with the contents of the play.htm from the sample.  This didn't run but after I added the additional .js files to default.htm it did.

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Express for the Web and the typescript 0.8.3.1 VS extension.  I'm using the Chrome browser on windows7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference here is how the compiler got invoked.

When you build the Mankala sample, assuming you read the README, you ran

`tsc Driver.ts -out game.js`

The `-out` flag tells the compiler to concatenate the compilation into one big .js file. However, the default behavior in Visual Studio projects is to build side-by-side, i.e. `base.ts` creates `base.js`, `Features.ts` creates `Features.js`, etc.

You can fix your project file by adding a `<TypeScriptOutFile>game.js</TypeScriptOutFile>` element to the project in the same `<PropertyGroup>` as the other TypeScript settings (near line 57 in a default new project). Be sure to add to both the `Debug` and `Release` `PropertyGroup` elements if you want the same behavior in both compilation settings, or create a new non-conditional `PropertyGroup`.